# How to modify the price of the dual spec?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, azerothcore

I would like to change the price of the dual spec in AzerothCore, how can I do that?

How to build the SQL query to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Short answer

```
UPDATE gossip_menu_option SET BoxMoney = XXXXXX WHERE OptionType = 18
```

replace with `XXXXXX` the actual price (in bronze) that you wish to apply. For example, for 500g it's `500`x`100`x`100` = `5000000`

### Explaination

If you use [Keira3](https://github.com/azerothcore/Keira3) and open any `Gossip Menu Option`, you'll see that different `Option Type` can be applied:

[image: Keira3 Gossip Menu Option dual spec]

and you'll notice that `18` is what we are looking for, thus we query for `OptionType = 18`

[image: Keira3 gossip menu option with dual spec]

You can find more info about how the tables `gossip_menu` and `gossip_menu_options` work in the official documentation:

- http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/gossip_menu
- http://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/gossip_menu_option